# ViewDragHelper on background of ActionBar

Tags: android, tabs, viewdraghelper

I'm using an Actionbar and a ViewDragHelper. But the components of the actionbar are on foreground of the viewGroup settled with ViewDragHelper : I cannot even touch the draggable view if a component is on the same place than a component of my ActionBar.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B81Yq5YsuKSwNVBMZWRwRDdtWnc/view?pli=1

The actionBar is settled like this:

```
android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Stuff1");
tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Stuff2");
tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Stuff3");

tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragment1,this));
tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragment2,this));
tab3.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragment3,this));

actionBar.addTab(tabSearch);
actionBar.addTab(tabPlayList);
actionBar.addTab(tabTest);
```

My ViewDragHelper is done in another class that extents ViewGroup:

```
public class YoutubeLayout extends ViewGroup {

    private final ViewDragHelper mDragHelper;
```

Is it because there are fragments that the components of the tab are upon the draggable view? Any ideas?

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: what do you meed ViewDragHelper for?

Comment: Because I'm playing youtube video on this draggable view. I can see the video in the bottom right corner, or drag it to the upper left corner to have the all the view and so see the playlist under the video (like new Youtube app).

Comment: so what does it have to do with ActionBar? you don't play your vid on it do you?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B81Yq5YsuKSwNVBMZWRwRDdtWnc/view?pli=1
As you can see the content of the tab is up to the draggable view. This is the problem.

Comment: seems that i really don't understand what you want to achieve...

Comment: On the image in the link I gave, on the left part, the draggable view is in the corner, it is the black window. Then, when I drag it to the upper left corner, it comes like on the second part on the image, on the right. The Textinput is on it, on foreground, and not hidden by it like I would like.

Comment: ok now its clear ;) by default the views are draw in the same order they are added to the parent view, so to fix your problem change that order

Comment: I tried to initialize the tabs before the setContent for the layout with the draggable view but it changed nothing...

Comment: did you try View.bringToFront() ?

Comment: Yes and the tabs components are still on foreground.

Comment: try to use hierarchyviewer to see if your dragged view and the tab content have the sane parent view

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B81Yq5YsuKSwdm1KQWpvVThDR2s/view?usp=sharing
Seems like the dragged view and the tab content have the same parent layout.

Comment: so the "blue" rect is drawn first and then "orange" rect is drawn, you have to inverse that order

Comment: I used this code onTabReselected in my tabListener and it's working : findViewById(R.id.dragLayout).bringToFront();
  findViewById(R.id.dragLayout).invalidate(); But the same code in onTabSelected doesn't work ...

Comment: Some news : when I'm calling this code in a button on a tab or onTabReselected : 
findViewById(R.id.dragLayout).bringToFront();
  findViewById(R.id.dragLayout).invalidate();
It's working, my draggable view go to foreground. But this code in onTabSelected is not working, can't understand why.

Comment: Honestly you shouldnt use bringToFront at all but rather change the order when child views are being added to the parent view